# Calculate and display frame per second of a game

Tags: java, algorithm

Has anybody ever been to this website?

http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d.html

It's got a nice Java-based game called Space Invaders and I like the tutorial of making the game so far.

And one of the tutorial questions is asking readers to calculate frame per second count in the game while it's running?

I'm really having trouble to make this work.

Can anyone help me out on this?  Thanks.

Comment: What's your thinking so far?

Comment: I hope [this question][1] and its answers may help you!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143495/how-do-you-calculate-fps-in-java-im-using-lwjgl-and-opengl

Comment: Thanks John.  This really help a lot.  
NPE - Sorry for no reply.  I was away from my computer desk for a while. I tried to use other people's examples in this forum, but I wasn't quite happy with the results I keep getting.. So had to reach out for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following code snippet (from Game.java)

```
public void gameLoop() {
        long lastLoopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // keep looping round til the game ends
        while (gameRunning) {
            // work out how long its been since the last update, this
            // will be used to calculate how far the entities should
            // move this loop
            long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLoopTime;
            lastLoopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

That should be a good startiing point for you to figure out the solution.